# Estimating parameters of a custom or constrained distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a custom distribution (an approximation of the skew normal), but I can't get Mathematica to use DistributionFitTest, EstimatedDistribution, or FindDistributionParameters on any custom distribution or a distribution where I have applied a constraint like

```
SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, (Sqrt[π] μ)/Sqrt[-π μ^2 + 2 σ^2]]
```

What I have currently is

```
data = RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[-.003, .01, 3], 150];

SNAPDF[x_, α_] := Piecewise[{
{0, x < -3/α},
{1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi])Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x + 3*α^2 x^2 + 
    1/3 α^3 x^3 + 9), -3/α <= x < -1/α}, 
{1/(4 Sqrt[2*Pi])Exp[-x^2/2] (3*α*x - 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 
    4), -1/α <= x < 1/α},
{1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi])Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x - 3*α^2 x^2 + 
    1/3 α^3 x^3 + 7), 1/α <= x < 3/α}, 
{Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[-x^2/2],3/α <= x}
}];

SNA[μ_, σ_, α_] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   SNAPDF[(x - μ)/σ, α]/σ, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> μ ∈ Reals && σ > 
      0 && α ∈ Reals];

EstimatedDistribution[
 data, 
 SNA[μ, σ, α], {{μ, -.01}, {σ, .01}, {α, 3}}]
```

I've looked through quite a few similar posts about topics like this but haven't found anything to solve my specific problems. Thanks!

Comment: Add code fill `data` variable.

Comment: Do you not need $\frac{\text{SNAPDF}\left(\frac{x-\mu }{\sigma },\alpha \right)}{\sigma }$ rather than just $\text{SNAPDF}\left(\frac{x-\mu }{\sigma },\alpha \right)$ in the definition of `SNA` ?

Comment: Good point! I have now fixed that in the post, but both of the problems still persist

Comment: I wonder if you should remove the reference to the constraints as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with estimating the parameters.  Also, with $\mu=-0.01$ and $\sigma=0.01$, the constraint has $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \mu }{\sqrt{2 \sigma ^2-\pi  \mu ^2}}$ being $\alpha=i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{\pi -2}}$ (an imaginary number).

Comment: I will edit the parameters inside the RandomVariate such that α remains real in the context of applying the constraint to the sample data! The end goal is to try to fit a constrained version of the SNA distribution to the data, but Mathematica won't fit a constrained nor user defined distribution.

Comment: "but Mathematica won't fit a constrained ... distribution".  Sure it does. `FindDistributionParameters[data, SkewNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma], 2 \[Mu]^2/\[Sigma]^2]]` works with the data you generated above.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you need to be able to use constraints but I don't see how that is related to the estimation problem you present.  But what you present is a real problem.

To obtain the maximum likelihood estimates I've slightly modified your code.  I think that your complicated `Piecewise` function where the conditions are highly dependent on the parameters (as opposed to conditions not involving the parameters) is bogging down the calculations in `EstimatedDistribution`.  (At least that's my guess.)

```
(* Generate data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[-.01, .01, 3], 150];

(* Initial values for parameters based on skew normal distribution *)
{μ0, σ0, α0} = {μ, σ, α} /. FindDistributionParameters[data, SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]];

(* Define log of the likelihood *)
logL[data_, μ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, α_?NumericQ] := Module[{f, x},
  f = Piecewise[{{0, x < -3/α},
    {1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x + 3*α^2 x^2 + 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 9), -3/α <= x < -1/α},
    {1/(4 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (3*α*x - 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 4), -1/α <= x < 1/α},
    {1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x - 3*α^2 x^2 + 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 7), 1/α <= x < 3/α},
    {Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[-x^2/2], 3/α <= x}}]/σ /. x -> (x - μ)/σ // Simplify;
  Log[f /. x -> #] & /@ data // Total
  ]

(* Maximize the likelihood *)
mle = FindMaximum[{logL[data, μ, σ, α], (Min[data] - μ)/σ >= -3/α, σ > 0}, 
  {{μ, μ0}, {σ, σ0}, {α, α0}}]
(* {554.03, {μ -> -0.0101752, σ -> 0.00993595, α -> 3.62204}} *)

(* Display data histogram and fit *)
Show[Histogram[data, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
 Plot[SNAPDF[(x - μ)/σ, α]/σ /. mle[[2]], {x, Min[data], Max[data]}]]
```

[image: Histogram and fit]

I'm also not understanding the purpose of performing a goodness-of-fit test.  You know for a fact that your `Piecewise` function is not a skewed normal.  No need to test for that.  What you would seem to want is a goodness-of-fit summary statistic or two or three summary statistics (certainly something other than a P-value).  In other words, what is it that would say that your estimation of the approximate density is close enough to what you can get by using a skewed normal?

**Obtaining estimates of standard errors for the parameter estimates.**

```
f = Piecewise[{{0, x < -3/α}, 
  {1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x + 3*α^2 x^2 + 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 9), -3/α <= x < -1/α}, 
  {1/(4 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (3*α*x - 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 4), -1/α <= x < 1/α}, 
  {1/(8 Sqrt[2*Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] (9*α*x - 3*α^2 x^2 + 1/3 α^3 x^3 + 7), 1/α <= x < 3/α}, 
  {Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[-x^2/2], 3/α <= x}}]/σ /. x -> (x - μ)/σ // Simplify;

(covMat = -Inverse[((D[Log[f], {{μ, σ, α}, 2}] /. 
  mle[[2]]) /. x -> #) & /@ data // Total]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Covariance matrix]

```
se = Sqrt[Diagonal[covMat]]
(* {0.000698432, 0.000786863, 0.930417} *)
```